# Reading date and time from CSV file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime, file-io, csv

```
datetime, M01, M02, M03, M04, M05, M06
8/15/2009 0:00, 5.8, 7.8, 7.8, 7.3, 0, 7.9
8/15/2009 0:10, 7.1, 8.1, 8.1, 7.7, 0, 8.1
8/15/2009 0:20, 6.8, 7.4, 7.6, 7.1, 0, 7.3
8/15/2009 0:30, 5.6, 6.8, 7.1, 6.6, 0, 6.8
8/15/2009 0:40, 3.9, 6.2, 6.4, 6.2, 0, 6.4
8/15/2009 0:50, 4.6, 5.5, 6.1, 5.8, 0, 5.6
8/15/2009 1:40, 7, 7, 7.2, 6.9, 0, 6.3
```

Can you help me to read this CSV file properly so I can convert the first column into a string using [datenum](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html)?
[csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html) of course does not work. With [textscan](http://www.mathworks.de/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) I am lost how to call it , so I do not get errors.
The date and time are in the same column.

Sorry it might sound a dumb question!!!

I know how to read read the above file now. but how do i write it back in a file.txt in the exact same format??
 i mean i modified some columns and now need a similar file with same format  for column 1 and row 1.
Thanks for the help

Comment: If the file contains comma-separated values, then where are the commas located in your above sample? Are there commas separating the date and time values?

Comment: No each field is separated by  commas. date and time is in one colum so no comma between it, its more like
8/15/2009 0:00:10,5.8,7.8,7.3,0,7.9

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to your comment above, if the data looks like:

```
datetime, M01, M02, M03, M04, M05, M06
8/15/2009 0:00, 5.8, 7.8, 7.8, 7.3, 0, 7.9
8/15/2009 0:10, 7.1, 8.1, 8.1, 7.7, 0, 8.1
8/15/2009 0:20, 6.8, 7.4, 7.6, 7.1, 0, 7.3
8/15/2009 0:30, 5.6, 6.8, 7.1, 6.6, 0, 6.8
8/15/2009 0:40, 3.9, 6.2, 6.4, 6.2, 0, 6.4
8/15/2009 0:50, 4.6, 5.5, 6.1, 5.8, 0, 5.6
8/15/2009 1:40, 7, 7 7.2, 6.9, 0, 6.3
```

then use the following to read it as a matrix:

```
fid = fopen('file.csv', 'rt');
a = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f', ...
      'Delimiter',',', 'CollectOutput',1, 'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);

format short g
M = [datenum(a{1}) a{2}]
```

... and the output I get:

```
M =
    7.34e+005        5.8        7.8        7.8        7.3          0        7.9
    7.34e+005        7.1        8.1        8.1        7.7          0        8.1
    7.34e+005        6.8        7.4        7.6        7.1          0        7.3
    7.34e+005        5.6        6.8        7.1        6.6          0        6.8
    7.34e+005        3.9        6.2        6.4        6.2          0        6.4
    7.34e+005        4.6        5.5        6.1        5.8          0        5.6
    7.34e+005          7          7        7.2        6.9          0        6.3
```

if you set the display [format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) to a long output, you will see the full numbers (note they are still stored in full), or use [fprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html):

```matlab
fprintf('%.9f\n', M(:,1))
```

```
734000.000000000
734000.006944445
734000.013888889
734000.020833333
734000.027777778
734000.034722222
734000.069444445
```

Comment: i had used a similar code and even when i copy your code get the same result
7.340000000000000   0.000058000000000   0.000078000000000
   7.340000069444445   0.000071000000000   0.000081000000000
   7.340000138888889   0.000068000000000   0.000074000000000
i have just copied the result of 3 rows n columns of the o/p
why are the numbers divided by 100000 ? when i try to do  M= [datenum(a(1)) a (2)] i get strange ans.
also when i change the dates i get the same set of string  in column 1 ,so i do not know what is happening.
Any clues?

Comment: Thanks a lot. you rock!!
 It works  now.
Can you explain me what the 'rt'   , 'collectoutput' does? 
 g after  format short  does?

you are awesome !!

Comment: You should simply consult the documentation for each function. `rt` stands for read and text mode (as opposed to binary mode). `collectoutput`: concatenates consecutive output cells with the same data type into a single array. `format short g`: uses best of fixed or floating point format (110.1 vs 1.1010e+002)

Answer (score 2):

TEXTSCAN by itself won't convert the date, but you can call DATENUM on just the column that needs it.

```
f = fopen('datafile.txt');
data = textscan(f, '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f', 'Delimiter', ',', 'HeaderLines', 1);
fclose(f);
data{1} = datenum(data{1});
```

will return a cell array `data` of doubles where the first column is the MATLAB datenum corresponding to each date, and each other column is the corresponding column from the file.