# How do I plot vectors of different length on the same axes in MATLAB?

Tags: file, matlab, timestamp

I am running into trouble trying to compare and plot two files of different length. In MATLAB I do not know how to plot two vectors of different length in the same x-axis. As one file has some data missing, I want to create a row and put blank space for that corresponding time stamp. Here are samples of data files:

*file 1:*

```
date time  T01  T02  T03  T04  T05
8/16/2009 0:00, 516.900024, 450.5,      465.200012, 546.799988, 539.700012
8/16/2009 0:10, 351.200012, 398.899994, 418.100006, 510.299988, 518.5
8/16/2009 0:30, 241.399994, 252.399994, 256,        360.600006, 386.5
8/16/2009 1:00, 184.199997, 154.300003, 143.899994, 236.600006, 244.399994
```

*file 2:*

```
date time  T01  T02  T03  T04  T05
8/16/2009 0:00, 656.799988, 611.200012, 860.599976, 604.700012, 288.5
8/16/2009 0:10, 527.400024, 359.200012, 789.099976, 789.099976, 446.799988
8/16/2009 0:20, 431.5,      327.100006, 763.599976, 895.099976, 689.099976
8/16/2009 0:30, 328.399994, 301.700012, 824,       1037.099976, 955.299988
8/16/2009 0:40, 261.5,      332.200012, 811.700012, 962.200012, 915.599976
8/16/2009 0:50, 180.300003, 291.100006, 700.099976, 855.200012, 836.900024
8/16/2009 1:00, 294.399994, 281.399994, 731.299988, 881.700012, 666.200012
8/16/2009 1:10, 274.899994, 334.200012, 759.400024, 913.900024, 760.799988
```

I am trying to remake file 1 as follows:

```
8/16/2009 0:00, 516.900024, 450.5,      465.200012, 546.799988, 539.700012
8/16/2009 0:10, 351.200012, 398.899994, 418.100006, 510.299988, 518.5
8/16/2009 0:20, ,,,,
8/16/2009 0:30, 241.399994, 252.399994, 256,        360.600006, 386.5
8/16/2009 0:40, ,,,,
8/16/2009 0:50, ,,,,
8/16/2009 1:00, 184.199997, 154.300003, 143.899994, 236.600006, 244.399994
8/16/2009 1:10, ,,,,
```

Is there a way to do this? it would help me a lot as I am trying to link up 2 files based on time stamps.

p.s.: I am trying to use the `ismember` function in MATLAB and am having all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are first reading data from the files as described in the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641519/reading-date-and-time-from-csv-file-in-matlab). If you have the time-stamps (converted using [DATENUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html)) and data from the two files stored in variables `fileData1` and `fileData2`, the following is a simple way to plot data from each on the same set of axes (using the function [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) and the [HOLD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html) command):

```
t1 = fileData1(:,1);  %# Time-stamps for file 1
d1 = fileData1(:,2);  %# First column of data for file 1
plot(t1,d1,'ro-');    %# Plot data from file 1, using a red line with circles
hold on;
t2 = fileData2(:,1);  %# Time-stamps for file 2
d2 = fileData2(:,2);  %# First column of data for file 2
plot(t2,d2,'bo-');    %# Plot data from file 2, using a blue line with circles
```

Each line in the above plot will have a different number of time points (i.e. circle markers), but each will be a continuous (i.e. unbroken) line. If you want to show breaks in the plot where there are missing time-stamps, you can pad the data from file 1 with [NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html) values. If you know for sure that there are never time-stamps in the smaller file that *aren't* in the larger file (i.e. that the time-stamps in the smaller file are a subset of the time-stamps in the larger), then you can use the function [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) as follows:

```
newData = nan(size(fileData2));      %# New file 1 data, initialized to NaN
t = fileData2(:,1);                  %# Use the time-stamps from file 1
index = ismember(t,fileData1(:,1));  %# Find row indices of common time-stamps
newData(:,1) = t;                    %# Copy time-stamps
newData(index,:) = fileData1;        %# Copy data
```

If there *are* time-stamps in the smaller file that aren't in the larger, then you will have to use a solution based on the [INTERSECT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/intersect.html) function (as illustrated in [my answer to your other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753033/timestamp-compare-files/1753680#1753680)).

And now, you can plot the data using the following:

```
d1 = newData(:,2);            %# First column of padded data for file 1
d2 = fileData2(:,2);          %# First column of data for file 2
plot(t,d1,'ro-',t,d2,'bo-');  %# Plot both lines
```

Here's a sample of the difference NaN-padding makes when plotting (using some randomly generated data):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, As you had seen from my other question that you commented too , i spend tons of time to figure the above problem.

Comment: @gnoice : is there a way to plot a matrix which is in cell format? normally i use > plot(x,y) x= data(:,1); y=data(:,2); how do i do the same when data is in cell? i tried cellplot, did not work. Also tried  x=cell2mat(data(:,1)) ; did not work either.

Comment: @AP: That depends on what your variable `data` looks like. Is it an N-by-2 cell array with one number per cell? Or is it a 1-by-2 cell array where each cell contains an N-by-1 vector? The first case can be handled like this: `plot([data{:,1}],[data{:,2}]);` And the second case can be handled like this: `plot(data{1},data{2});` Without more detail about what `data` looks like, that's the best I can answer.

Comment: @gnoice: Its a N,M matrix, I make it work by writing a xlsfile and rereading it as data=xlswrite(' ') ; This seems like a round about way of doing it. With either of the two commands it gave the same error ' invalid first data argument '

Comment: @AP: Do you mean to say `data = xlsread(...);`? Using XLSWRITE will just return a logical flag for the value of `data` indicating whether the write operation was successful. If you use `data = xlsread(...);`, your matrix `data` will be a numeric array, not a cell array, so you should be able to plot it with `plot(data(:,1),data(:,2))`.

Comment: @gnoice: Sorry if i confused you. I know i can plot the way you mentioned. Ok here is what i am doing.  I have a file of size (20 20) and its in cell as i have processed and did many operations on it. now in the end i am writing a xlsfile... using xlswrite ('newfile.xls', file);

NOW i wanna plot  column 1 Vs Column 2 of file.
is there anyway of not doing agian

data= xlsread ('newfile.xls')

and then plotting?

is there a way to convert my cell format to num so i can plot directly from file?

Comment: @AP: Ahhhh, I've got it now. The problem is likely that you have strings in the top row of your cell array `file`. Those strings are causing the error you were getting. You have to pick only those cells with numeric values in them for the plotting. If your strings are only in the top row of `file`, this should work: `plot([file{2:end,1}],[file{2:end,2}]);`

Comment: @gnoice: Yes you are right yet agian :P. I had empty strings on the first row and last 5 rows and so i had the problem. I guess there is no way to delete the empty rows  i used 

file = file(~any(cellfun(@isempty,file),2),:);  but did not work