# How do I account for missing data when creating an Excel file in MATLAB?

Tags: file, matlab, timestamp

I had posted a [similar question related to plotting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647817/how-do-i-plot-vectors-of-different-length-on-the-same-axes-in-matlab), and now I'd like to know how to handle missing data when outputting data to an Excel file using the [XLSWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html) function.

I have two sets of data of different length (described in the question I link to above). I am trying to replace the smaller file with zeroes for the times when the data is missing. This is the code I tried to use:

```
newfile2 = zeros(144,20);
[ts,ifile1,ifile2] = intersect(file1(:,1),file2(:,1));
newdfile2(ifile2,:) = file2;
```

Here, I have already converted the column 1 data to a number using [DATENUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html).
So `ifile2` is giving me indices of times that are common to both files. The problem is I get this error for line 3:

```
((??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. ))
```

This is because the size of `file2` is **130-by-20**, but my `file1` is of size **144-by-20**. I also tried a different approach using [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) to find the missing indices and still got the same error.

Can someone please give me some guidance?

Comment: The problem is unclear. It sounds like you have one file with some time-stamped data, and a second file with a smaller amount of time-stamped data. Are the time-stamps unique (i.e. no repeated time-stamps in a file)? Does the same data appear in the 2 files (i.e. entire rows are the same)? You haven't made it clear what you're trying to do and why. Can you give some sample data file contents?

Comment: yes timestamps are unique in file and do not repeat, its a data set for a day. first column in each file is time stamp for the day.  some files have missing data( so i am replacing it by 0 to all column for that timestamp row) example   file1 =(  0.0   23  3 4; 0.10  25 6 7; 0.2  22 7 8; 0.3  20 8 9)
file2= (0.0 34 4 8; 0.2 31 9 0)

Comment: @AP: I revised your question based on extra information from the comment discussions. I think this version makes it clearer what you are looking for, but if I've inadvertently changed the intent feel free to roll it back or re-edit it.

Comment: @AP: Happy to help. FYI, as the asker of the question you are entitled to choose an "accepted answer" (i.e. the answer you found most helpful) by clicking the check mark underneath the vote counter for the answer. This gives the answerer +15, gives you +2, and often gives other users more incentive to answer your questions. I'm not trying to beg for Rep, I'm just letting you know about it since you are still relatively new to SO. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that will allow you to output "empty" cells to your Excel worksheet is to make the data a cell array with empty values or blanks instead of zeroes, using one of the following options:

```
newData = cell(size(fileData1));  %# Each cell is initialized to []
[newData{:}] = deal('');          %# Change the cell contents to an empty string
[newData{:}] = deal(' ');         %# Change the cell contents to a blank
```

There are then two ways to proceed. If the time-stamps in the smaller file are only ever a subset of the ones in the larger (i.e. there is never a time-stamp in the smaller file that *is not* in the larger), then you can just use the [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) function as follows:

```
t = fileData1(:,1);                      %# Time-stamps from file 1
index = ismember(t,fileData2(:,1));      %# Find index of common time-stamps
newData(:,1) = num2cell(t);              %# Copy time-stamps
newData(index,:) = num2cell(fileData2);  %# Copy file 2 data
```

However, if there *are* time-stamps in the smaller file that aren't in the larger, you should instead do the following using the [INTERSECT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/intersect.html) function:

```
t = fileData1(:,1);                                  %# Time-stamps from file 1
[junk,index1,index2] = intersect(t,fileData2(:,1));  %# Find indices
newData(:,1) = num2cell(t);                          %# Copy time-stamps
newData(index1,:) = num2cell(fileData2(index2,:));   %# Copy file 2 data
```

The above will discard any time-stamps that are in the smaller file but not in the larger. If you want to include this extra data then include the following additional code (which uses the functions [SETDIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/setdiff.html) and [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html)):

```
[junk,index] = setdiff(fileData2(:,1),t);           %# Unique time-stamp indices
newData = [newData; num2cell(fileData2(index,:))];  %# Add unique data
[junk,index] = sort([newData{:,1}]);                %# Sort the time-stamps
newData = newData(index,:);                         %# Reorder the data
```

Now, if you use [XLSWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html) to output `newData` to an Excel file, the padding cells should show up as empty, although the documentation for XLSWRITE has these remarks:

> Full functionality of `xlswrite` depends
>   on the use of the Microsoft Excel COM
>   server. The typical installation of
>   Excel for Windows includes access to
>   this server. If your system does not
>   have Excel for Windows installed, or
>   if the COM server is unavailable,
>   `xlswrite`:
>
> - Writes matrix `M` as a text file in
>     comma-separated value (CSV) format.
> - Ignores the sheet and range arguments.
> - Generates an error if the input matrix
>     `M` is a cell array.
>
> If your system has Microsoft Office
>   2003 software installed, but you want
>   to create a file in an Excel 2007
>   format, you must install the Office
>   2007 Compatibility Pack.

Comment: Thanks , i will work on this and let you know . Honestly i am really thankful.

Comment: gnovice you are amazing. it works great on my matlab version at home, will let you know tomorrow if it had any problems in the  older version i use at work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to copy from file2 to newfile2, and you want to copy the data that has timestamps that exist in file1, and you want newfile2 to be the same size as file1.

```
newfile2 = zeros(size(file1));
[ts,ifile1,ifile2] = intersect(file1(:,1),file2(:,1));
newfile2(ifile1,:) = file2(ifile2,:);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I am little confused. when i ran my code i did not get the error i wrote above.i have a newer version of matlab than my office. 
thanks a lot.Your code also works fine on my  home matlab version . i need to check to see if it works in the older version in my office or i get the same error.
thanks

Comment: Another followup question:

is there a way to keep those rows empty and not have zero in excel sheet by the matlab code? ( rows on which the smaller file have missing data)

Comment: @AP: That depends... How are you writing data to the file?

Comment: @mtrw: I think you have to add `newfile2(:,1) = file1(:,1);` so that the time-stamps themselves aren't zero.

Comment: @gnovice: I am using xlswrite to write the file that i am generating 'newfile2'
and to read the data file initially i was using textscan

Comment: @gnovice - thanks for catching that.  @AP - sorry I wasn't around after you asked your followup, looks like gnovice took good care of you :)