# read and rewrite in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

[How do I write a text file in the same format that it is read in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905061/how-do-i-write-a-text-file-in-the-same-format-that-it-is-read-in-matlab)

I looked and my question is almost the same as above question.
I want to read in a file which is 84641 x 175  long.

and i want a make a new .txt file with 84641 x 40 , deleteling rest of the columns.
I have 2 rewrite the dates n times. date is on first column in format 6/26/2010 and time on 2nd column in format '  00:00:04'

when i use the code put in above question i keep getting the error

> ??? Error using ==> reshape
>   Product of known dimensions, 181,
>   not divisible into total number
>   of elements, 14812175.
>
> Error in ==>
>   write at 
>   data = reshape(data{1},N+6,[])';

when i comment this it has error in printf statements for date and data write.

Any ideas??
thanks

Comment: Does your data file have *the same* format as the one in that question? Did you set the value of `N` properly? (`N` is the number of columns of data *after* the date and time)

Comment: yes i am counting it properly. i even tried all combinations , 173-178.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905061/how-do-i-write-a-text-file-in-the-same-format-that-it-is-read-in-matlab/1908361#1908361) in the question you link to, I'll try to explain what I think is going wrong.

The code in my answer is designed to read data from a file which has a date `XX/XX/XXXX` in the first column, a time `XX:XX:XX` in the second column, and `N` additional columns of data.

You list the number of elements in `data` as 14812175, which is evenly divisible by 175. This implies that your input data file has 2 columns for the date and time, then 169 additional columns of data. This value of 169 is what you have to use for `N`. When the date and time columns are read from the input file they are broken up into 3 columns each in `data` (for a total of 6 columns), which when added to the 169 additional columns of data gives you 175.

After reshaping, the size of `data` should be 84641-by-175. The first 6 columns contain the date and time values. If you want to write the date, the time, and the first 40 columns of the additional data to a new file, you would only have to change one line of the code in my answer. This line:

```
fprintf(fid,', %.1f',data(i,7:end));  %# Output all columns of data
```

Should be changed to this:

```
fprintf(fid,', %.1f',data(i,7:46));   %# Output first 40 columns of data
```

Comment: Another question how do i selectively pick the headers?
i am doing

fprintf(fid,', %.1f',data(i,7:46));
fprintf(fid,', %.1f',data(i,47:50));
and some more 

how do i pick the headers and write?

when i try

columnHeader = {'col1','col2','col3'};
fprintf(fid,'%s',columnHeader); 


??? Undefined function or method
'fprint' for input arguments of
type 'cell'.

Error in ==>

fprint(fid,'%s',columnHeader);

Comment: @Paul: To print your cell array of header labels, you could do this:
`fprintf(fid,'%s\t',columnHeader{:}); fprintf(fid,'\n');`. You could also replace the `\t` after the `%s` with one or more spaces, if that makes your output file look better.