# Importing date & time data from a txt file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime, file-io, import

I have a txt file from which I want to load date & time data. UI import wizard ignores date & time string and loads only numeric data, which is also present in the file.

How can I write a script that would load this date & time data as a vector of multiple values (I mean, 1st date, 2nd date and so on). I know how to manipulate this string with datestr & datenum, my problem lies within loading data.

The file looks like this:

```
{headerlines}

15/11/08-12:17:00 423.85        234.54                672.42 
15/11/08-12:17:10 456.54        245.98                723.41  
15/11/08-12:17:20 478.65        320.67                952.73
```

I have a problem only with loading this date&time string. I can manage numeric data.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641519/reading-date-and-time-from-csv-file-in-matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look at [Reading Data in a Formatted Pattern](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/import_export/f5-35378.html#f5-6432).

While not taking care of your header, a solution could look like this:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt');
dateItem = [];
values = [];
while ~feof(fid)
  [dateItem]= [dateItem ; fscanf(fid,'%s',1)]; 
  [values]= [values ;fscanf(fid,'%f %f %f',3)'];
end
fclose(fid);
```