# Taking numbers from multiple files and store it as one 4xn matrix

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix

I have files of type Xseed0001.txt, Xseed0002.txt, etc in the same directory

The content of Xseed0001.txt

```
 PeakValue for Martin   1 :    2.2582E+08
 PeakValue for B        2 :    7.9025E+07
 PeakValue for DFG       3 :    9.1502E+00
 PeakValue for BBB      4 :    1.1790E+06


---------------------------------------------
----       Successfully  Completed       ----
---------------------------------------------
```

How do I store a matrix A of these four REAL NUMBERS (not 1,2,3,4) multiplied by the number of seeds so different values from the other files goes into next row?

so that A= [2.2582E+8 7.9025E+7  9.1502E+00 1.1790E+06 ; (new values for seed0002,3,4 here, etc)]

Comment: What did you try? Did you try using `textscan`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1641519/1336150), for instance?

Answer (score 0):

files = dir('C:\directory\Xseed*.txt'

for fi=1:numel(files)
     fid=fopen(files(fi).name);

S{fi} = fscanf(fid,'%*s %*s %*s %*d  %*s %f',[1 inf]);

A(fi,:) = [S{fi}(1), S{fi}(2), S{fi}(3), S{fi}(4)];

end

fclose(fid);